# Ability to offer only part of the node resources?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, dcos

Using dc/os we like to schedule tasks close to the data that the task requires that in our case is stored in hadoop/hdfs (on an HDP cluster). Issue is that the hadoop cluster is not run from within dc/os and so we are looking for a way to offer only a subset of the system resources.

For example: say we like to reserve 8GB of memory to data node services, then we like to provide the remainder to dc/os to schedule tasks.

From what i have read so far, the task can specify the resources it requires, but i have not found any means to specify what you want to offer from the node perspective.

I'm aware that a CDH cluster can be run on dc/os, that would be one way to go, but for now that is not provided for HDP.

Thanks for any idea's/tips,
Paul

Comment: I'm not sure the exact answer to your question, DC/OS' resource management is done by Mesos, so if there is a way to only offer part of the resources on a node to a cluster, it would be described within the [Mesos resource management documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/#resource-management)

Comment: I found the --resources "..." option on the mesos agent that i could use to statically reserve resources to a role that is not used by dc/os (so in fact only used by HDP). Not sure if that is the best solution; or if there are other concerns when sharing a node between two cluster/solutions...?